# How do I include a downloadable PDF in a register form?

Tags: php, html, forms

I am coding a register form and need to include a pdf file next to a checkbox. The pdf file contains important information that the user needs to agree to before sending the form. When you click on the file name that appears next to the checkbox, the browser must ask you if you wanna view or download the file.

How do I realize this?

Comment: You could use a conditional statement, and if all requirements are met, you'd use [`include`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or show (echo) the link to the hidden file, placed outside public folder.

Comment: `<a href="link-to-pdf.pdf" target="_blank">IMPORTANT PDF</a>` ? To be sure, prepend disposition headers to the pdf

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I would put the contents in a scrollable div to make it easier to read on all devices. You can always mail the pdf after the registration has been sent in.

Comment: @jeroen awesome idea! how do I achieve that a pdf is viewed inside a html box?

Comment: No, you'd need plain text / html for that. I don't think all browsers can show a pdf inline.

Comment: Plus, not all mobile devices can view/handle PDF files @jeroen

Answer (score 0):

The way I would go about this is create a download directory "*/downloads*" and inside there put a php file named index.php with the following code

```
<?php
$file = 'http://example.com/download/' . $_GET['file'];  //Thanks DanFromGermany!
if($file == 'http://example.com/download/index.php'){die;}
$file_headers = @get_headers($file);

if(substr_count($file_headers[0], '404 Not Found') || substr_count($file_headers[0], '410 Gone')){
    exit;
} else {
    if($file == 'http://example.com/download/index.php'){die;}
    header ("Content-type: octet/stream");
    header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET['file'].";");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
    readfile($file);
    header('Location: http://example.com/thanks'); //send them to a thanks page or close the window, whatever works for you
    exit;
}
?>
```

Place whatever files you want to be downloaded (read_this.pdf) Then link them as follows

```
<a href="/download?file=read_this.pdf" target="_blank">Download this PDF</a>
```

any filename you point to with the file being placed inside "*/downloads*" **will force their browser to download it**.

**edit however** I agree with Jeroen's suggestion about putting it in a scrollable div. to do this the file would need to be html though but you could use something like http://www.pdftohtml.net/ to make the html look just like the pdf did. I personally leave a website when it tries to force me to download something because you never know what it could be. I only use this method when giving someone a file to download. otherwise, hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: It should be pointed out that your example offers everyone the possibility to download any file on the server. e.g. `/download?file=config.php`

Comment: @DanFromGermany Sorry about that, I completely overlooked that, is that better?

Comment: You're just doing the work of a web server in PHP, if you place the PDF in the `/downloads` directory and just link to the file with `<a>` you'll get the same result (minus the redirect) and you're not using PHP for the job a web server can do.

Comment: @ChrisWhite But it's not, if you link to a pdf the browser will load it from the site in the browser, setting the headers "Content-disposition: attachment" which would force the file to download to the computer rather than display in the browser.